# How to safely map dtos to entities ( Automapper -> Entity Framework )

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

i've few doubts on automapper.
I'm currently using it in a project and it works perfectly fine, i'm using it for mapping entities to dtos and viceversa, but i'm pretty scared of the implicit behaviors while the project grows.
I'm pretty sure i'm missing something because i didn't find a lot of resources that treat this argument and usually is a good indicator that i'm a little bit off, otherwise more people would have the same doubts.

Now, here one of my doubts.
Let's say that i've an entity which containes a collection of sub-entities, something like:

```
public class Parent
{
 ...
 public List<Child> Childs = { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}

public class Child
{
 ...
}
```

Now, i create the related dtos, so i'll have ( ParentDto and ChildDto ).

Now i've a service like this:

```
public async Task SaveParents(List<ParentDto> dtos, int userId)
{
    //i load the entities from db inlcuding the childs of the parents
    var dbEntities = await blablaRepo.GetParentsWithChild(userId); 
    
    //map from dto to entities
    mapper.Map(dtos, dbEntities); 
    
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Everything works fine up to here.

Now, let's say 6 months from now i add another class and the related Dto

```
public class InnerChild{
...
}
```

and i change my previous child class to contain a list of InnerChild like:

```
public class Child
{
 ...
 public List<InnerChild> InnerChilds = { get; set; } = new List<InnerChild>();
}
```

Now, if in the blablaRepo.GetParentsWithChild(userId) i mistakely add an Include(child=>child.InnerChilds) i'll have my context also containing the InnerChilds and this means that my SaveParents Method could inadvertently delete all my InnerChilds within the Parent hirearchy.. am i correct??

because:

```
//this line would load everything, including the innerChilds
var dbEntities = await blablaRepo.GetParentsWithChild(userId); 

//this would map the dtos to the entities but since the dtos does not contain any innerChild but it's initialized at an empty list it will blank the innerChilds of the entity
mapper.Map(dtos, dbEntities);
```

This scares the hell out of me because it's like i'm always "one include away" from a potential disaster.

Other than that i'm also worried about the potential doors that i leave open, for example, let's say that i define a method to remove child from parents with a business rule within it, something like:

```
public void RemoveChild(Child childToBeRemoved)
{
if(Childs.count>10)
    Childs.remove(childToBeRemoved);
else
    throw new Exception("You can remove childs only if you have more than 10");
}
```

now if i map from the DTO i'm actually "bypassing" the method and potentially leave the class properties in an invalid state.

Am i wrong??

Should i use automapper only to map from entities to dtos and do the rest manually?
am i missing something here?

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: AFAIK, if you have in EF core a 1:n relationship and you make an update of the parent entity with an empty list nothing happens to the childs. To remove those childs you have to explicitly remove these childs by calling the remove methods for each child entity to mark them as deleted. While I'm not completely sure, I would suggest you to test it. 

Comment: Unless you have an anemic domain model, AM should not be useful when mapping to entities. Because that's the very logic of your app, nothing auto about it. See also [this](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/). But it's more about the design of your app than it's about AM.

Comment: @Oliver thanks for the answer.
No, actually with the Automapper.Collection package AM is able to understand the changes in the collection. So if an empty collection is provided in the DTO it will assume that the mapped entity need to have the collection cleared. I think that the only way to prevent this is having the collection null in the DTO, in that case the entity collection should not be touched ( not 100% sure )

Comment: @Lucian, thanks for the suggestion actually i kind of agree with you it was one of the first solutions that came to my mind. Do you have any other resource where i could get more info on the best practices? thank you very much

Comment: About AM, I already posted a link. In general, you need some domain driven design resources to get an idea about what can be done. For some friendly material, check https://codeopinion.com/.